# Unable to encode a tiff file properly, Some characters are not encoding

Tags: java, encoding, base64, tiff, decoding

I have TIFF file which contains multiple images , I will need to loop through that TIFF file to extract the images seperately ,
I have used base64 encode, then used substring to seperate the images and used base64 decode to write in a filesystem,
 However only some images are able to extract.

Example : I have 7 Images in a tiff file but it extracted only 4 images.

So I have write the encoded data to a file and read that and I can only able to see the II* encode character as 4 places instead of 7 .. 
When I open the TIFF file using notedpad , I can see 7 II* . Please advise , the best method to do this.

I have tried to decode the ecoded file and it is correct, It has 7 II* , however in the ecoded file I can only see the 4 encoded(SUkq) value of II*.

I can't use the below code , as my TIFF file contains header part before the II* which will need to remove before I use the below method.

class

```
 public void  doitJAI() throws IOException {
    FileSeekableStream ss = new FileSeekableStream("D:\\Users\\Vinoth\\workspace\\image.tif");
    ImageDecoder dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", ss, null);
    int count = dec.getNumPages();
    TIFFEncodeParam param = new TIFFEncodeParam();
   param.setCompression(TIFFEncodeParam.COMPRESSION_GROUP4);   
    param.setLittleEndian(false); // Intel
    System.out.println("This TIF has " + count + " image(s)");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        RenderedImage page = dec.decodeAsRenderedImage(i);
        File f = new File("D:\\Users\\Vinoth\\workspace\\single_" + i + ".tif");
        System.out.println("Saving " + f.getCanonicalPath());
        ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
        pb.addSource(page);
        pb.add(f.toString());
        pb.add("tiff");
        pb.add(param);
        RenderedOp r = JAI.create("filestore",pb);
        r.dispose();
    }
}
```

so Im using the below code , this is just to extract the first image .

Class

```
public class SplitTIFFFile {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new SplitTIFFFile().doitJAI();
}

File file = new File("D:\\Users\\Vinoth\\workspace\\Testing\\image.tif");

    try {

                FileOutputStream imageOutFile;
                /*imageOutFile*/ try ( /*
                 * Reading a Image file from file system
                 */ FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                    byte imageData[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
                    imageInFile.read(imageData);
                    /*
                    * Converting Image byte array into Base64 String
                    */
                    String imageDataString = encodeImage(imageData);
                    String result = imageDataString.substring(imageDataString.indexOf("SUkq") , imageDataString.indexOf("SUkq"));
                    /*
                    * Converting a Base64 String into Image byte array
                    */
                    byte[] imageByteArray = decodeImage(result);

                    /*
                     * Write a image byte array into file system
                     */
                    imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Users\\Vinoth\\workspace\\Testing\\image_converted_Vinoth_2.jpg");
                    imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray);
                }
        imageOutFile.close();

        System.out.println("Image Successfully Manipulated!");
    }

            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Image not found" + e);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception while reading the Image " + ioe);
    }

}

/**
 * Encodes the byte array into base64 string
 * @param imageByteArray - byte array
 * @return String a {@link java.lang.String}
 */
public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageByteArray){        
    return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageByteArray);        
}

/**
 * Decodes the base64 string into byte array
 * @param imageDataString - a {@link java.lang.String} 
 * @return byte array
 */
public static byte[] decodeImage(String imageDataString) {      
    return Base64.decodeBase64(imageDataString);
}

}
}
```

Comment: Tiff is a binary format. It usually is better not to try to force the binary data into a textual form for manipulation using string operations but instead use binary operations all along.

Comment: Hi , can advise how I can open a tiff file and replace some strings ? I will need to replace II* with 2 spaces in the front and 2 spaces afterward of II* ?

Comment: You are aware that tiff files internally use offsets for many structure references and that replacing certain sequences with others can break these references? Furthermore you surely only want to replace in the values of certain tags (or memory regions referenced by them), not e.g. in the image data.

Comment: My tiff doesn't start with II* so I first need to remove those header part that are before the first II*

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not use a conversion of `byte[]` to a Base64 String and then search "SUkq".

SUkq represent 3 bytes (ASCII `II* = byte[] { 73, 73, 42 }`), but when those same 3 bytes are shifted 1 or 2 positions, a totally different string happens, needing 5 letters.

The code with byte only:

```
    byte[] imageData = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

    final byte[] soughtBytes = { 73, 73, 42 };
    int from = indexOf(imageData, soughtBytes, 0);
    from += soughtBytes.length;
    int to = indexOf(imageData, soughtBytes, from);
    if (to == -1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    byte[] imageByteArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(imageData, from, to);

    Path imageOutFile = Paths.get(
                "D:\\Users\\Vinoth\\workspace\\Testing\\image_converted_Vinoth_2.jpg");
    Files.write(imageOutFile, imageByteArray);
}

static int indexOf(byte[] totalBytes, byte[] soughtBytes, int start) {
    for (int index = start; index <= totalBytes.length - soughtBytes.length; ++index) {
        boolean equal = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < soughtBytes.length; ++i) {
            if (totalBytes[index + i] != soughtBytes[i]) {
                equal = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (equal) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This saves the bytes *between* the first two "II*".

*Not tested.*